# NetworkXError: Adjacency matrix not square: nx,ny=(737, 39)

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

How can I solve this error?

```
import networkx as nx
df=pd.read_excel('peso-ao-nascer.xlsx')
```

`G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(array)`

So I have this:
NetworkXError: Adjacency matrix not square: nx,ny=(737, 39)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do by passing a 737x39 array to `nx`. The [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix.html) say is should be "an adjacency matrix representation of a graph", which by definition is square (both dimensions are the same). It would much easier to help if you made a small example of data you are starting with and what you hope to get as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjacency matrices must be square because the "index" of the rows and columns are from the same set, the set of the nodes in the graph.

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#:%7E:text=Adjacency%20matrix,-From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the)

> In graph theory and computer science, an adjacency matrix is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph. The elements of the matrix indicate whether pairs of vertices are adjacent or not in the graph.

Therefore, in order to fix your issue, you have to determine why there is a case where a non-square matrix is being used as an adjacency matrix.

Likely:

- There is an issue with where you are getting that matrix, and they did not provide an appropriate adjacency matrix
- You are using a matrix which was not meant to be an adjacency matrix
- You do not mean to use that matrix as an adjacency matrix

Sorry if my answer is a bit general, it is hard to provide a more specific answer without more information.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, using the correlation matrix that is square.